# why commenting the throw new IllegalArgumentException in code below gives error for line "return typeofDay" as "variable not initialized"

Tags: java

```
public String getTypeOfDayWithSwitchStatement(int dayOfWeekArg) {
     String typeOfDay;
     switch (dayOfWeekArg) {
         case "Monday":
             typeOfDay = "Start of work week";
             break;
         case "Tuesday":
         case "Wednesday":
         case "Thursday":
             typeOfDay = "Midweek";
             break;
         case "Friday":
             typeOfDay = "End of work week";
             break;
         case "Saturday":
         case "Sunday":
             typeOfDay = "Weekend";
             break;
         default:
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid day of the week: " + dayOfWeekArg);
     }
     return typeOfDay;
}
```

Commenting the following line, throws compilation error:

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid day of the week: " + dayOfWeekArg);
```

Also `typeOfDay` is treated as uninitialized variable.

But why it is not treated as uninitialized variable before.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose that `dayOfWeekArg` contains something else than the name of a day, so in the `switch` statement the `default` case is reached.

If you do not throw the exception there, execution will continue to the `return` statement at the bottom of the method, but `typeOfDay` will not have been set to any value. That's an error.

If you do throw the exception, the `return` statement can never be reached when `dayOfWeekArg` contains anything else than the name of a day, so there is no problem.

Answer (score 3):

Because if your code flow goes through the default section, and 
there's no exception thrown there your variable typeOfDay will 
indeed be uninitialized. While when there's an exception thrown, 
the compiler knows that you cannot pass through the default 
section and continue downwards after it (as the exception will be thrown).

Answer (score 3):

Read through your switch statement:

The variable will be assigned a value if it equals to one of the cases, right? But what happens if it does **not** equal one of the statements? Then it should go through the **default** case.

If you have the default case with a `throw new...` then nothing is going to be returned to the user and it doesn't matter whether the variable is initialized or not. Now when you comment the `throw new...` the compiler realizes that there is a **possibility**  of returning the variable typeOfDay without a value, since it didn't go through any of the case statement and the default one doesn't do anything to it.

It is trying to save you a headache by warning you of a **possibility** of returning the variable without a value. This can be solved by initializing your variable.